# Manipulating data in a collection with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I use the following:

```
        var menuItems = _menuRepository.GetPk(pk)
            .Where(m => m.Status == "00")
            .OrderBy(m => m.Order)
            .Select(m => new MenuItem
            {
                PartitionKey = m.PartitionKey,
                RowKey = m.RowKey,
                Order = m.Order,
                Link = m.Link
            });
```

To retrieve a collection of strings such as these below. All strings are the same length (8 columns) and are sorted in order:

```
0-0-0-00
0-1-0-00
0-2-0-00
0-3-0-00
1-0-0-00
1-1-0-00
1-1-1-00
1-1-2-00
1-1-3-00
1-2-0-00
3-1-0-00
3-2-0-00
```

What I need to do is if given a string such as "1-1-1-00" then I need to retrieve all the rows from the menuItems list, where the first four columns match the input string except the one row where there is a zero in the 5th column. Such as:

```
1-1-1-00
1-1-2-00
1-1-3-00
```

Comment: "Such as:" - did you forget to paste something there?

Comment: Thanks I added the output. Is my question clear? It's kind of difficult to explain. I'm not even sure if I can do this with LINQ. Maybe something in a for loop would be easier?

Comment: what 5th column you taking about ?!!

Comment: Your question is not clear at all!

Comment: The 5th column of the 8 column strings. The one with the sequence: 1,2,3 in the last example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String input = "1-1-1-00";
var wantedStrings = stringList.Where(str => str.StartsWith(input.Substring(0, 4)) && str[4] != '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string given = "1-1-1-00";
string sptGiven = given.Split('-');
var result = stringList.Where(m => m.Split('-')[0] == sptGiven[0] && 
                              m.Split('-')[2] == sptGiven[2] && 
                              m.Split('-')[3] == sptGiven[3]);
```

Comment: instead of calling split three times on each string you could wrap the lambda body up in {} assign to a variable once and then use that. Hoever since the strings are fixed length you can simply index into it an compare the character

Comment: +1, you're absolutely right i just copied and paste it 2 timed to be the first answer